# Multiplication of pulse trains

Tags: rf, pulse, multiplication

Suppose I have two pulse trains, with pulses some tens of nanoseconds apart and long (evenly spaced and equally for both of them). Each of the pulses has some amplitude \$v_n\$ in one train and \$v_n'\$ in the other.

How (if possible) would one go about creating a third pulse train from these in which the individual pulses have the multiplied amplitude \$v_nv_n'\$?

Comment: \$v_n\cdot v_n^{\:'}=\exp\left(\ln\left(v_n\right)+\ln\left(v_n^{\:'}\right)\right)\$. Convert the voltages to currents (simple resistor will do that) and then push that through a diode and add the resulting voltages. (May require a bias offset added to that.) Then apply the resulting summed voltage to a diode to get back a current. Then a resistor to convert that back to a voltage. So looks like some diodes to me. Your short "tens of nanoseconds" is another issue. But I'll leave that to others.

Comment: What pulses are contained in the third train? Does it contain train_1 pulses, train_2 pulses or, something else? What is this third pulse train used for?

Comment: Is this for some measurement problem? If so, you'll have to tell us what your requirements in error magnitude and distribution are; multiplication is practically never exactly possible in analog domain, but you can bound the error you're making, but with really drastically increasing difficulty the lower your error needs to be. So, please: absolute magnitude ranges for \$v_n, v'_n\$ and a relative error limit that follows from your *requirements*, not a feeling of "as good as possible".